# Hiding text annotation when zooming in on a plotly graph

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

The first graph below is the default view where I have inserted a text annotation to mark the line. When I zoom in though to see the (barely visible) bottom area of the graph, the text annotation still sticks but without the line and hence, making no sense. Is there a way I could hide it when the user zooms in?

[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
world_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/master/world_df.csv')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.population, fill='tozeroy')
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_cases, fill='tozeroy', mode='lines', line_color='#0099ff')
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.herd_immunity_threshold)
fig.update_layout(annotations=[dict(x=0.5, y=0.7, xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False,
                                    text='something something line')])
```

Comment: Can you share your code so that your graph is reproducible?

Comment: Hi. Completely slipped my mind for some reason. Added it now. And [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/master/world_df.csv) is the data.

Comment: Added the data import in the code block itself

Comment: Awesome! This will be really helpful to anyone wanting to answer your question, including me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters `xref='paper'` and `yref='paper'` will place the annotations relative the to chart instead of the actual coordinates. That means because you have `y=0.7`, your annotation will remain in the position 70% of the way between the bottom and top of the chart no matter how much you zoom. Instead you should set the `yref='y'` and then pass the coordinate to the parameter `y` (I set it to 5.222515 billion based on the trace of your original plot).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
world_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/master/world_df.csv')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.population, fill='tozeroy')
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_cases, fill='tozeroy', mode='lines', line_color='#0099ff')
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.herd_immunity_threshold)
fig.update_layout(annotations=[dict(x=0.5, y=5.222515*10**9, xref='paper', yref='y', showarrow=False,
                                    text='something something line')])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes! Why didn't I think of that. It makes sense to change y_ref. Thanks

Comment: No worries! I would say in general the documentation is a good place to look first

Comment: I started from the docs (where I got `paper` from) but I should have revisited them and that would have helped me, you're right.

Comment: It's all good! Everything takes a bit of practice :)